# Magento Paypal standard partial refund change order state to complete

Tags: paypal, magento-1.5

I am getting issue with paypal standard on my Magento 1.5.1.0 ,Below is the scenario:

- I am working with sandbox account
- After payment , paypal IPN changes my order state to "Processing" from "Pending Payment".
- Now I go to my paypal account and issue a partial refund like if order total is 20$
  , I refund 2$.
- Now in response Paypal IPN do two things on magento

  1. Change order state to complete [**This is the issue it shouldn't
     change the state to complete because I had done a partial refund
     from order amount**]
  2. Create credit memo of 2$ and send email to customer.

The code I found is :

File     : app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Ipn.php

function : _registerPaymentRefund

Code     :

```
**Here order status is "Processing" checked via Mage::log**

    $payment = $this->_order->getPayment()
                ->setPreparedMessage($this->_createIpnComment($this->_info->explainReasonCode($reason)))
                ->setTransactionId($this->getRequestData('txn_id'))
                ->setParentTransactionId($this->getRequestData('parent_txn_id'))
                ->setIsTransactionClosed($isRefundFinal)
                ->registerRefundNotification(-1 * $this->getRequestData('mc_gross'));

        $this->_order->save();

**Here order status is "Complete" checked via Mage::log**
```

Below are the screen for more clear view first one is for magento and another one is for paypal :

[image: Screen at magento]

[image: screen at paypal]

It will be really appreciable if some one can guide me which function in above code changing order state from "Processing" to "Complete"

Comment: I got some sort of solution here http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3405/process-to-create-partial-credit-memo-refund-for-paypal-standard-orders , but they are disabling automatic credit memo creation and sending admin notification to create credit memo manually.I want credit memo remain automated,please help guys ?

Comment: Hi, If you read the referred question, you will see the persons involved are well experienced in magento, and they came up with the most viable solution. Their reasoning is sound, and I am sure they tried everything to make this automated. You are asking the same thing, thus marking the question as duplicate of that. sorry.

Comment: Hi.sorry I can't agree.I am trying for fix,not to convert the things for manual processing.any help will be really appreciated to debug this magento core issue.